# Elasticsearch query not working how I expected

Tags: java, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to Elasticsearch, so I'm clearly misunderstanding some aspect of it.  But, here goes...

I'm using DynamoDB to store my data, and have an AWS Lambda indexing each record in Elasticsearch.  I can see the data being indexed properly.  For example, here is one such document:

```
{
    "_index": "question",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "quis-vari-1331252716",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 0,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "questionKey": "QUESTION#quis-vari-1331252716",
        "data": {
            "downVoteCount": 0,
            "communityIdentifier": "community-14213442297707724",
            "authorIdentifier": "9513a57c-3816-4c5d-8376-400aacd9deca",
            "title": "quis varius venenatis accumsan suscipit sit massa ",
            "questionText": "justo Ut rhoncus eleifend Pellentesque aliquet luctus urna mi Quisque dapibus sedSed nec posuere arcu tortor amet in mollis a in vel bibendum sed a commodo ligula Vestibulum penatibus...",
            "commentCount": 0,
            "score": 0,
            "answerCount": 0,
            "createdDate": "2022-08-08T20:14:07.512Z",
            "lastUpdate": "2022-08-08T20:14:07.512Z",
            "viewCount": 0,
            "voteCount": 0,
            "upVoteCount": 0,
            "favoriteCount": 0,
            "uniqueIdentifier": "quis-vari-1331252716",
            "realmIdentifier": "realma"
        },
        "communityKey": "REALM#realma#COMMUNITY#community-14213442297707724",
        "sk": "REALM#realma#COMMUNITY#community-14213442297707724#QUESTION#quis-vari-1331252716",
        "pk": "REALM#realma#COMMUNITY#community-14213442297707724#QUESTION#quis-vari-1331252716",
        "type": "QUESTION"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `data` element has a couple of identifier fields.  Now, I would like to query for the document (there should only be one out of hundreds) that matches the following:

- `data.uniqueIdentifier` = quis-vari-1331252716
- `data.communityIdentifier` = community-14213442297707724
- `data.realmIdentifier` = realma

Using the [RestHighLevelClient](https://javadoc.io/static/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.6.0/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.html), I created a `SearchSourceBuilder`, `BoolQueryBuilder`, etc. and executed the search.  The resultant query -- based off a print statement -- looked like this:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must":[
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "data.uniqueIdentifier":{
                              "value":"quis-vari-1331252716",
                              "boost":1.0
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "data.communityIdentifier":{
                              "value":"community-14213442297707724",
                              "boost":1.0
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "data.realmIdentifier":{
                              "value":"realma",
                              "boost":1.0
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative":true,
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   }
}
```

As far as I can tell, everything looks good.  However, when I run the query I get zero returned results.  I'm clearly not constructing my query properly, either because I'm misunderstanding how to build the query itself, or because of the structure of the data.  Is the issue the fact that I'm trying to query properties below `data`?  Do I need to do something to index my DynamoDB entity differently if it has embedded objects? Any idea what I'm doing wrong and to get back the expected document?

Comment: what is the type of the fields in the mapping? Try add .keyword in fields like this: data.uniqueIdentifier.keyword, data.communityIdentifier.keyword and data.realmIdentifier.keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `keyword` type of field as you are using a `term` query. OR you can use a `match` or `match_phrase` query if you want to search on `text` fields.

Also, my understanding here is, you are using dynamic field mapping of elasticsearch and it will create most of all field with `text` and `keyword` type.

You can check index mapping with below API from Kibana:

```
GET question/_mapping
```

You can try below query with term query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "data.uniqueIdentifier.keyword": {
                    "value": "quis-vari-1331252716",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "data.communityIdentifier.keyword": {
                    "value": "community-14213442297707724",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "data.realmIdentifier.keyword": {
                    "value": "realma",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Why result are not coming with current query?**

Because when you use `term` query it will look for exact match and it will not work on `text` type of field because text field are analyzed using analzyer while indexing. Hence, you need to use `keyword` type of the field as it is not analyzed.